# Search AD by GUID

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, ldap

How do I search Active Directory for objects by GUID? In other words, what would be a good way to find what objects belong to specified GUIDs?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/140683/get-an-object-by-its-objectguid-using-ldapsearch Provides one method.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Either on a DC or install RSAT and enable AD Tools:

Open "Active Director Module for Windows PowerShell" (find it in with the other Admin tools)

```
get-aduser -id {guid}
```

Or for any object:

```
get-adobject -id {guid}
```

Might want to pipe it through a `format-list` to make it readable:

```
get-adobject -id {guid} | fl
```

Comment: +1, simplest answer with native tools. If you're at a regular powershell prompt and don't want to open the AD Module for PS in the start menu you can just run `import-module ActiveDirectory` and all of the same cmdlets will be available in your powershell session.

Answer (score 3):

Using Powershell and the [QuestAD cmdlets](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx), the following code returns my user account based on my guid.

```
$Guid = "d65e4578-475a-422e-ac99-123456789012"

Get-QADUser -IncludeAllProperties|Where {$_.guid -eq $Guid}
```

Not the most efficient manner since it loads all objects from AD while doing the search, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$guid = "d65e4578-475a-422e-ac99-123456789012"

foreach ($dom in (Get-adforest).Domains) { Get-ADObject -filter {ObjectGUID -eq $guid } -Properties * -Server $dom | fl }
```

Answer (score 1):

ADSI is installed by default on Windows.

Does not require installing any additional modules.

Powershell Example:

```
# define constants
$LDAPserver = "DeathStar.Empire.Galactic"
$GetItem  = "GUID=d65e4578-475a-422e-ac99-123456789012"

# use this if you have a SID
# $GetItem  = "SID=S-1-1-555-423432-437584356"

# Get the Distinguished Name
$DistinguishedName = $([ADSI]"LDAP://$($LDAPserver)/<$($GetItem)>").DistinguishedName

# Use the distinguished name to fetch the actual object
$Searcher = [ADSISearcher] ([ADSI] "LDAP://$(LDAPserver)")
$Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(DistinguishedName=$($DistinguishedName)))"
$AdsiObject = $Searcher.FindAll()

# Get the ADSI object properties
$AdsiObject.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's a lot easier to do than how all the other answers show.  Each code-block below is a standalone method, you can do any of them (they're mostly the same).**

Obviously Remote Server Administrator Tools (RSAT) needs to be installed, or you need to be working on a Domain Controller (DC).

If you're using the SID, i.e. the folders within a Recycle Bin, permissions on a folder, etc. (they all begin with S-1-), you can do:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { SID -eq "S-1-5-21-000-000...0001" } | select Name, GivenName, Surname, SID
```

or for multiple, add an OR:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { SID -eq "S-1-5-21-000-000...0001" -or SID -eq "S-1-5-21-000-000...0002" } | select Name, GivenName, Surname, SID
```

Or if you have them all in an array, iterate over the array:

```
$MyArray = "S-1-5-21-000-000...0001", "S-1-5-21-000-000...0002"
$MyArray.ForEach( { Get-ADUser -Filter { SID -eq $_ } | select Name, GivenName, Surname, SID  })
```

If you're actually searching by GUID:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { OBjectGUID -eq "e257c3da-9388-0000-00...0001" } | select Name, GivenName, Surname, SID
```

Clearly, the above are when searching for Users.  You can search any object:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter { OBjectGUID -eq "e257c3da-9388-0000-00...0001" } | select Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID
```

Or for objects by ObjectGUID if you have them all in an array:

```
$MyArray = "e257c3da-9388-0000-00...0001", "e257c3da-9388-0000-00...0002"
$MyArray.ForEach( { Get-ADObject -Filter { OBjectGUID -eq $_ } | select Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID })
```